# Tensorflow 2 can't be imported (PyCharm)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I can't import TF2 in PyCharm. I installed it with reh requirements.txt and tried different Versions (latest and 2.0.0). However when I want to import it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A704601/PycharmProjects/Projekt/src/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\A704601\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\A704601\PycharmProjects\Projekt\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I have the latest Version of Windows 10 and PyCharm. I use Python 3.6 and I do not have a GPU but my CPU supports AVX. Furthermore this solution I found did not solve the problem:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: A similiar issue is discussed here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046

Can you try to pin protobuf to 3.6.0 with `protobuf==3.6.0` in your requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

As Rumo mentioned in the comments installing protobuf==3.6.0 fixed the issue